# Writing Fortran subroutine outputs to a file Running from Python interface

Tags: python, fortran, fortran90, f2py

Below is the Fortran code that I am running and I want to save the `Qr` values to a file. This subroutine is called and executed in python.

```
subroutine thrustTorque(n, Np, Tp, r, precurve, presweep, precone, &
Rhub, Rtip, precurveTip, presweepTip, T, Q)

implicit none

integer, parameter :: dp = kind(0.d0)

! in
integer, intent(in) :: n
real(dp), dimension(n), intent(in) :: Np, Tp, r, precurve, presweep
real(dp), intent(in) :: precone, Rhub, Rtip, precurveTip, presweepTip

! out
real(dp), intent(out) :: T, Q

! local
real(dp) :: ds
real(dp), dimension(n+2) :: rfull, curvefull, sweepfull, Npfull, Tpfull
real(dp), dimension(n+2) :: thrust, torque, x_az, y_az, z_az, cone, s
integer :: i
```

*There is long list of more variables and their definations here, which I am skipping.*

```
cone =0.0_dp
z_az = 0.0_dp
! integrate Thrust and Torque (trapezoidal)
thrust = Npfull*cos(cone)
torque = Tpfull*z_az
```

Now here `Qr(i)` values I want to be saved in a file.

```
T = 0.0_dp
do i = 1, n+1
    ds = s(i+1) - s(i)
    T = T + 0.5_dp*(thrust(i) + thrust(i+1))*ds
    Q = Q + 0.5_dp*(torque(i) + torque(i+1))*ds
    Qr(i) = Q
end do
end subroutine thrustTorque
```

I tried this:

```
T = 0.0_dp
open (1, file = 'data1.dat', status ='new')
do i = 1, n+1
    ds = s(i+1) - s(i)
    T = T + 0.5_dp*(thrust(i) + thrust(i+1))*ds
    Q = Q + 0.5_dp*(torque(i) + torque(i+1))*ds
    Qr(i) = Q
    write(1, *) Qr(i)
end do
close(1)
end subroutine thrustTorque
```

This subroutine is called in python using:

```
T, Q = _oxi.thrustTorque(Np, Tp, *args)
```

I cannot return the values of `Qr` as this is also linked to other areas of the code and will require many changes. Instead, I would prefer if I can print the output in Terminal or save them in a file.

Although the program is executed I don't see the results being saved in a file or even a file being created.

Comment: Are you sure that the newly modified subroutine is actually being called?

Comment: Yes can print the values `T` & `Q` obtained from `_oxi.thrustTorque`, they are available. @francescalus

Comment: But if you've modified the subroutine to handle the file writing, etc., it's possible that you're still using the object of the old version without that?

Comment: I am working inside a virtual environment, every time I run these values should be calculated again. @francescalus

Comment: Troubleshooting suggestions: Can you create and write to *any* file at some other point in your code? If this fails, can you create the file with Python before calling the Fortran subroutine, and access it via the subroutine? Is the file path what you expect it to be?

Comment: @MattP #1. No I am not able to create a file from Fortran itself. #2. I created a file from Python before calling it in Fortran subroutine, it is been accessed (as I can see its modified) but no values are written. #3. File path is correct.

Comment: Nothing is written...Well, try the Fortran [`flush`](https://software.intel.com/en-us/node/679280) intrinsic, maybe. Or try writing with the [`iomsg`](https://software.intel.com/en-us/node/680026) specifier or other error indicators to return a msg about possible issues.

Comment: @MattP Ok I used this: `open (unit=101, file="guru99.txt", status='old', IOSTAT=IERR, ERR=100, IOMSG=msg-var)` but got no error messages.

Comment: @MattP Can you show me the syntax for iomsg in the write command. I don't think its right, what I used.

Comment: Oki @francescalus was correct it was still using the old version, I had to update my code after the changes so that interface knows an update has been made. Do this using: `f2py -c -m codename codename.f90`

Answer (score 1):

Several issues stand out:

1. You use file unit 1 -- that's not a good idea. Fortran uses these low numbers often for specific units, i.e. standard out, error out, standard in. Better use this syntax:

   ```
   integer :: u ! unit for file i/o

   open(newunit=u, file='data1.dat', status='new', action='write')
   do
       ...
   end do
   ```

   That way, you can be sure that the unit number is free.
2. The `write(*, *) <data>` always writes to standard out -- you should have seen the values being displayed on screen when you ran it. In order to write to a file, you need to replace the first `*` of the `write` statement with the file unit.

   ```
   write(u, *) Qr(i)
   ```

Comment: Based on your point #2 I didn't get any output in terminal when `write(*, *) <data>` was used. And after following the steps still, no file is created.

Answer (score 0):

Oki @francescalus was correct in the comments it was still using the old version, I had to update my code after the changes so that interface knows an update has been made. Do this using: `f2py -c -m codename codename.f90`

**Edit:** Oki after running some tests on this, I am able to print and create a file but this has to be in a separate subroutine, I don't understand this. looks like it has something to do with import function. `import _codename` is diffrent from `import codename`. If anyone can explain this, please let me know.

Comment: Ok with further digging into finding the difference between `import _codename` and `import codename`. I found it is related to `f2py` invocation. You can either define appropriate invocation which in my care is difficult or let the python do it itself by installing the setup.py with `python setup.py install develop --user `. This builds on the changes made in Fortran and allows python to call them